# CSS input[type=checkbox]:checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure out why this will not work for me. I have a CSS checkbox that I want to reposition background when checked. Can someone tell me why this isnt working?

Here is original code:
HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<label>Flight</label>
```

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox]{
display: none;
}


input[type=checkbox] + label{
display: inline-block;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
padding-left: 40px;
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
line-height: 32px;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
background-position: left -32px;
}

label{
background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_d2a60beb8fb6bbb280642579049ebf65.png); 
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/colbydodson/pen/hiaFL)

Here is fixed code:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="travel_check" />
<label for="travel_check">Flight</label>
```

Comment: Where did you read you can use curly braces that way?

Comment: Your codepen code doesn't even have a `input{type=checkbox}:checkbox` selector in it... what are you _actually_ asking?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Use curly braces in what way? Please elaborate?

Comment: Right, given the accepted answer I guess the code in the question title wasn't real code. I've fixed it for you but next time please note that you're expected to post real code and you should do it in the question itself.

Comment: I've reverted my edit. You've apparently edited the linked code after getting an answer. Voting to close instead; this question is of no use for anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label is not defined to point to the checkbox. In this case, you'll need an `id` on the checkbox and a corresponding `for` on your label.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eauxc

Comment: Thank you! I wasnt aware I need an `id` and a `for`.

Comment: I'm confused. The original code seems to already have those.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario It didn't when I clicked the codepen link that was there before being edited...

Comment: Alright... That's why Stack Overflow rules require to include relevant code *in the question itself*. I'm voting to close: the code the question is about does not exist any more.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I pasted in original code along with the fixed code. I also reverted the Demo so users could see original code.

Comment: the linked pen does not work without internet access,  it refers an image in the internet...

Comment: @TobiTiggers Yes... You need internet access to access things on the internet...

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: Of cource I did not mean the pen itself but the the code in the pen references an image in the internet. so the checkbox example does not work for e.g. an intranet enviornment. :-)